# JSF selectonemenu can't instantiate class

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to create a select one menu object in my JSF application. Whenever I try to fill the list I get 'can't instantiate class' exception. Here is my bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "districtController")
@SessionScoped
public class DistrictController implements Serializable {

    private District current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private TestoBeans.DistrictFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;


    public DistrictController() {

        Query q = em.createQuery("select d.dName from District d",District.class);
        List<String> values = q.getResultList();

        for(String d:values){
            System.out.println(d);
        }

    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestoIBBPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private javax.transaction.UserTransaction utx;

    public District getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new District();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    private DistrictFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
        if (pagination == null) {
            pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
                @Override
                public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                }
            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }

    public String prepareList() {
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String prepareView() {
        current = (District) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "View";
    }

    public String prepareCreate() {
        current = new District();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
        return "Create";
    }

    public String create() {
        try {
            getFacade().create(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("DistrictCreated"));
            return prepareCreate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String prepareEdit() {
        current = (District) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "Edit";
    }

    public String update() {
        try {
            getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("DistrictUpdated"));
            return "View";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String destroy() {
        current = (District) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        performDestroy();
        recreatePagination();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String destroyAndView() {
        performDestroy();
        recreateModel();
        updateCurrentItem();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            return "View";
        } else {
            // all items were removed - go back to list
            recreateModel();
            return "List";
        }
    }

    private void performDestroy() {
        try {
            getFacade().remove(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("DistrictDeleted"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    private void updateCurrentItem() {
        int count = getFacade().count();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= count) {
            // selected index cannot be bigger than number of items:
            selectedItemIndex = count - 1;
            // go to previous page if last page disappeared:
            if (pagination.getPageFirstItem() >= count) {
                pagination.previousPage();
            }
        }
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            current = getFacade().findRange(new int[]{selectedItemIndex, selectedItemIndex + 1}).get(0);
        }
    }

    public DataModel getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return items;
    }

    private void recreateModel() {
        items = null;
    }

    private void recreatePagination() {
        pagination = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        getPagination().nextPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String previous() {
        getPagination().previousPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = District.class)
    public static class DistrictControllerConverter implements Converter {

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            DistrictController controller = (DistrictController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "districtController");
            return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof District) {
                District o = (District) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getId());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + District.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private Map<String,String> district = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public Map<String, String> getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(Map<String, String> district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public void persist(Object object) {
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.persist(object);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: `can't instantiate class exception` is usually throw when there is some exception thrown inside your constructor.

Comment: yes I know. Actually I am confused about how to fill the dropdown list by using Entity manager.

Comment: @AliYucelAkgul Nobody can help you unless you find what exception is being thrown in the constructor and post the stacktrace.  I also highly suggest that you not execute queries in an object constructor.  That is extremely poor design and leads to difficult debugging as you have already found out.

Comment: Ok. I will consider it. thanks a lot.

Comment: In future problems, do not ignore the exceptions. They are not for decoration, they contain the answer. You'd have noticed that it's caused by a `NullPointerException` on `em`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the entityManager in your constructor. As injections has not yet happend then

instead move this code to a method annotated @PostConstruct

```
@PostConstruct
public init() {

    Query q = em.createQuery("select d.dName from District d",District.class);
    districtValues = q.getResultList();

    for(String d:districtValues){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Method annotated @PostConstruct will be invoked after your EM and EJBs has been injected.

A tip when learning about dependency injections is to keep the examples really small and just get basic end-to-end functionality to work.